# Iris Colour Picker: get selected colour as RGB value

Tags: javascript, colors

Using the Iris colour picker, is it possible to get the selected colour in rgb format? Currently I always get the selected colour as a hex code.

http://automattic.github.io/Iris/

```
<input class"col-picker"/>

....

$('.col-picker').iris({
    mode: 'rgb', // doesn't return colour in rgb
    change: function(evt, ui) {

        console.log('colour as rgb', ui.color.toString());

        // Above always outputs hex values not rgb
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Iris plugin uses Color.js under the hood, which again includes color conversion tools.

Calling `$(elemet).iris('color', true)` get you the Color.js object, which has a `toCSS` method that will return the color in most available formats

```js
$('.col-picker').iris({
  mode: 'rgb', // doesn't return colour in rgb
  change: function(evt, ui) {
    var color = $(this).iris('color', true).toCSS('rgb');
    console.log(color)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://automattic.github.io/Iris/javascripts/iris.min.js"></script>

<input class="col-picker" />
```